# In django, Is it ok to write duplicate methods in different applications if method code is small?

Tags: python, django, class, object, architecture

I am working on web api using django.
In this I have categorized functionality with different applications.

I need suggestion for following scenario-

- Suppose I have three applications in a project, app1, app2 and app3
- There is one function with name func(), func() require in app1 and app2
  and may require in app3 in future. This function has same code, require same parameters.

So, should I write func() in app1 and app2, also if require in app3. or write in only app1 and call it into app2. which is best approach for above scenario?

- does creating class object of class from app1 and calling method func() from another application cause performance issue if that class contains lot of code?
- or simply write a new method in application even though it is redundant

Please suggest me best approach. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If that function is required in all the apps, then it should be an utility function.

The best approach is to create a file for common utils which are needed by multiple apps in a common location independent of all apps and import that file inside the required apps.

Best coding approach is that only application specific codes should be present inside the application code, and each app should be independent.

So your directory structure can be as follows:

```
Django-project
    common-utils
       utils.py
    app1
       app1-code
       utils-specific-for-app1
    app2
       app2-code
       utils-specific-for-app2
```

so `app1` and `app2` should import `common-utils` if required